# Compare byte array (received mqtt message) to zero to send notification

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, mqtt

I'm building android app that receives an mqtt message from esp8266 with the percent of water on water sensor for my school project.
So, I need to send app notification, when the percent is not equal to zero, but there's one problem. Received message is a byte array, but for some reason it's not just number, it has specific U+FFFD � replacement character, so I can't compare this byte array to another array like [0]. I'm trying to convert received message into string, remove all strange symbols and compare it to "0". But for some reason again I can't. For example, String "0����" clears from all the � characters, but the java code still considers that it is not equal to "0".

My code:

```
if (topic.equals(topicstr2)){
                    byte[] res = message.getPayload();
                    result_notif = new String(res).replaceAll("�", "");
                    if (result_notif != "0"){
                        sendNotif();
                    }
                }
```

result_notif is a string, it was declared in the beggining of code.

P.S. sorry for my bad english, I hope I've made my problem pretty clear.

Comment: Try `!result_notif.equals("0")` to compare the string to zero. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/7947994).

Comment: @JANO no, with !result_notif.equals("0") it still considers that 0 procent is not "0":(

Comment: Ok, what is the output if you print out the variable `result_notif`?

Comment: @JANO just "0" without any empty spaces, my notification includes that "result_notif" string, I use .setContentText(result_notif + "%!") and it works fine, printing "0%!"

Comment: Does specifying the charset make a difference like this: `result_notif = new String(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: @JANO It doesn't make any difference

Comment: Ok, can you print the length `System.out.println(result_notif.length());` and also the ASCII value of the zero character: `System.out.println((int) result_notif.charAt(0));`?

Comment: @JANO omg, THANK YOU. The string length was surprisingly equal to 6! I used the .trim() method and everything worked well! Thanks for quick response!!! I've been fighting with this code for 3 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `!result_notif.equals("0")` instead of `"result_info != "0"`" and using the `.trim()` method was the solution of my problem.

Code:

```
if (topic.equals(topicstr2)){
    byte[] res = message.getPayload();
    result_notif = new String(res).replaceAll("�", "").trim();
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_RESULT, result_notif);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    if (!result_notif.equals("0")){
        sendNotif();
    }
}
```

Comment: That may work for the moment but it is a bad hack. You should decode the content of the byte array in the right way. But... you did not tell what exactly this array contains.. So we cannot give help.

Comment: @blackapps  the byte array contains one number from 0 to 100 without any "%" characters.

Comment: That tells us not much. Would 99 be two bytes or one? Both is possible. It could be four bytes too if it was sent as an integer. You should tell us exactly how many bytes and the content of every byte. You could give examples.

Comment: @blackapps ok, I checked it. After the first connection to mqtt even if the percent is "0" array contains 10 bytes, then numbers from 0 to 9 - 1 byte and from 10 to 99 - 2 bytes. The percent was sent as a string.